# Encountering error while adding MaybeT dependency in stack project

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am following this tutorial [webScraper](http://adit.io/posts/2012-03-10-building_a_concurrent_web_scraper_with_haskell.html#full-code-listing) using HXT.
I am using Stack here.

While adding dependency for MaybeT, it asked to:

> Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in /Users/***/Haskell Development/Scraper/stack.yaml:

- MaybeT-0.1.2

Now doing so to ended up with this message on running stack build:

> In the dependencies for MaybeT-0.1.2:
> base-4.9.0.0 must match <4.8 (latest applicable is 4.7.0.2)
> needed due to Scraper-0.1.0.0 -> MaybeT-0.1.2

Being new to Stack, I am unable to solve the problem, in my cabal file the
the dependency:

```
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                    ,  hxt
                    ,  url
                    ,  HTTP
                    ,  MaybeT
```

In stack.yaml

```
resolver: lts-7.12
extra-deps: [MaybeT-0.1.2]
```

What is it that I have missed. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for your concrete problem is switching from the [outdated *MaybeT* package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MaybeT-0.1.2) to the `MaybeT` transformer offered by the transformers package in [`Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html).

---

That said, note that the version mismatch involves *base*. If you actually needed to use the *MaybeT* package, you would have to switch the Stack resolver to a snapshot such as [`lts-6.26`](https://www.stackage.org/lts-6.26), which uses *base-4.8* or below (i.e. GHC 7.10.3 or below). *base* versions are coupled to GHC versions, and everything else depends on *base*, so there is no easy way of switching just *base* to an older version, as it might be possible, given some luck, with other packages.